# Replace multiple fields with one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, sql-update

Instead of running two separate queries to replace the `innerSku` and `outerSku` fields in my `parts` table, is there a way to do this in one query without affecting performance?

```
UPDATE 
    parts
SET 
    innerSku = @newSku
WHERE
    innerSku = @oldSku;


UPDATE
    parts
SET
    outerSku = @newSku
WHERE
    outerSku = @oldSku;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stick to two separate statements, since using following will update some rows which doesnt need to be updated, it will update the rows to itself, which will not change the data but unnecessary updates operations will take place, I would say stick to two updates. anyway following is how you can update this table with one update statement.

```
UPDATE Parts 
  SET innerSku = CASE 
                      WHEN innerSku = @oldSku 
                      THEN @newSku ELSE innerSku 
                 END
     ,outerSku = CASE 
                      WHEN outerSku = @oldSku 
                      THEN @newSku ELSE outerSku 
                 END
 WHERE innerSku = @oldSku OR outerSku = @oldSku
```

Comment: And depending on how the table is indexed, you may be adding a mess of index updates and extra time where the range or table is locked.  Plus the two simple statements are more readable (and testable).

Comment: True @Rawheiser agreed 100%

Answer (score 4):

The case statement becomes your where condition determining what value to set, only updating the column that meets the condition, otherwise it will just set the current value back.

The where clause makes it so you don't run the statement on your whole table.

```
SET parts.innerSku = (CASE WHEN innerSku = @oldSku THEN @newSku ELSE innerSku END),
    parts.outerSku = (CASE WHEN outerSku = @oldSku THEN @newSku ELSE outerSku END)
WHERE parts.innerSku = @oldSku or parts.outerSku = @oldSku
```

Comment: **+1** for providing a good answer. I chose the other answer as the accepted solution though because it outlines the drawbacks of using this approach.